# Retrieve fields from Mysql to gridview

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to retrieve information into a gridview If I use below it works

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OdbcDataAdapter oda = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM patchtest", con);
        oda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
```

I built a query with Navicat query builder and it works with NaviCat and retrieves the information I am looking for. When I try below my program just closes with no error.

```
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OdbcDataAdapter oda = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT members.`Code`patchtest.PatchID,patchtest.Description,patchtest.Employee,patchtest.Date,patchtest,Results FROM members,patchtest WHERE members.`Code` = patchtest.MemberID", con);
        oda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
```

Comment: Typo perhaps?  You are missing a comma in the beginning of your `select` statement.

Comment: Where am i missing a comma?

Comment: Try your select in the MySql command window!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to spot errors like this when you format your code.

- First you need a comma in between your first 2 fields in your `select` statement.
- Second you have `patchtest,Results` when you should have `patchtest.Results`.
- Finally I would recommend using a `join` over commas in your `from` clause.

---

```
SELECT members.Code, 
       patchtest.PatchID,
       patchtest.Description,
       patchtest.Employee,
       patchtest.Date,
       patchtest.Results 
FROM members 
       JOIN patchtest on members.Code = patchtest.MemberID
```